# Как изменить текст "я согласен с политикой конфиденциальности" на странице регистрации Ucoz

Tags: текст, регистрация, ucoz

Не могу найти где можно изменить текст на странице регистрации (ucoz) (пользовательское соглашение) [image: скриншот регистрации страницы]  "я согласен с политикой конфиденциальности" ( I agree to the website's Privacy Policy)
Локальные пользователи, куплен пакет оптимальный.

Comment: пакет чего? какая cms?

Comment: @КириллПанишев *яровой* (Не по теме, извините)

Comment: извините не уточнила, что это на ucoz

Comment: @Karina Думаю, это лучше у самого Ucoz спрашивать...